# Текст съезжает с кнопки при изменении размера страницы

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите исправить, вот код проблемный

```css
.button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  min-height: 40%;
  min-width: 40%;
  max-height: 40%;
  max-width: 40%;
  position: relative;
}
.text {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-justify: auto;
    max-block-size: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="block2preset" text-align: center;>
        
        <button class="button">

            <h1 class="text">
            button
                </h1>

        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: реально помогите, я не понимаю в чем проблема

Comment: Нажми ф12 и посмотри как ведет себя этот н1. Скорее всего кнопка размер меняет, а заголовок нет. И почему бы просто не обойтись без н1? Написать этот button в кнопке?

Comment: оно ведет себя точно так же , h1 нужен чтобы текс увеличить и отредачить, без него оно так же себя ведет, я его для этого в h1 и взял, чтоб посмотреть как это исправить, и нет, тут как раз таки заголовок размер меняет, это и надо исправить, что не менял, они у меня в div заключены

Comment: мне надо чтобы текст влезал в кнопку при любом увеличении, а не чтобы оно масштабировалось, мне желательно вообще эту функцию убрать,

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container1, .container2, .container3, .container4 {
            width: 150px;
            height: 101px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .red {
            width: 150px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }
        .beige {
            width: 150px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: wheat;
        }
        .aqua {
            width: 150px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: aqua;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }
        .yellow {
            width: 150px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: yellow;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }
        .green {
            width: 150px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: green;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }
        button {
            width: 100px;
            height: 20px;
            font-weight: bolder;
            margin-left: 25px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container1">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="beige">
            <form action="#">
                <button>button</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="aqua"></div>
        <div class="beige">
            <form action="#">
                <button>button</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container3">
        <div class="yellow"></div>
        <div class="beige">
            <form action="#">
                <button>button</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container4">
        <div class="green"></div>
        <div class="beige">
            <form action="#">
                <button>button</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

И никуда Ваш button не денется ;-)